# How to pass input value to href

Tags: php, forms, post, hyperlink

I have a form with method post and with a text box and button to submit.

I can easily grab the value with `$_POST` but I want to be able to pass this value to a link.

textinput = search term

link = `index.php?search=search term`

If I just concoctenante it into the href I get the value $search isn't set because `$search` gets set on `$_POST`.

I know this is possible, `wowhead.com` is an example, although id rather not use javascript, just css html and php.

Thanks!

Using form method get works but it also passes my button value to the url

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
    <table style="border:0px">
        <tr>
            <td style="border:0px">
                <input id="search" name="search" autocomplete="off" type="text" maxlength="32" style="width:350px;" />
            </td>
            <td style="border:0px">
                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search" style="font-size:16;padding:3px;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Shows up like this:

```
http://localhost/search.php?search=searchterm&submit=Search
```

I want to not have `&submit=Search`

FIXED by changing

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search" style="font-size:16;padding:3px;" />
```

to (got rid of name tag)

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" style="font-size:16;padding:3px;" />
```

Comment: Try with $_REQUEST instead of $_POST ;-)

Comment: Please provide some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `get` method

```
<form action="index.php" method="GET">
    <input type="search" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

OR

```
<form action="index.php" method="GET">
    <input type="search" name="search" />
</form>
```

and in php you grab the value by `$_GET['search']`

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed. The only problem though is that when I use get it also passes the submit button like this

http://localhost/search.php?search=searchterm&submit=Search

Comment: I have posted two forms! Check the other some without submit button